# discrepancy between development and production pdf generated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, wkhtmltopdf

I've Iterated over the creation of a PDF with data in my RoR application. I am using wkhtmltopdf 0.9.9 locally and trying to use wkhtmltopdf-binary (0.9.9.1) gem on heroku.

My PDF looks exactly the way I want it to look locally but it looks like the heroku version is a zoomed out version of the local version effectively making the page on heroku left align when the development version is perfectly centered.

I'd like my production version to look exactly like my development version so that I don't have to iterate on my heroku instance. 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The problem you have to overcome is using the same versions for development when it comes to wkhtmltopdf. We found differences between the OSX and Ubuntu versions down to the QTlibrary dependencies - we ended up building an Ubuntu VM to develop in locally to match the environment as close as we could.

Comment: Thanks! I had someone try on ubuntu and it looks like you are correct!  on ubuntu the local version looks just as wrong. Now just need to iterate to fix!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but setting DPI, while generating pdf via `wkhtmltopdf`, solved the problem.

```
--dpi 100
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Wiked_pdf has a :dpi option, that was already set to 100, but it was actually doing --dpi "100" so I tried adding --dpi 100 to the :extra hash and commenting out the :dpi option but wasn't successful.

Comment: @NicholasStock: I know, this is "default", but in practice on my unix box ti wasn't; setting dpi on both sides, unix and windows, I now get same PDF as output. Can you show me your full wkhtmltopdf call with parameters?

Comment: thanks for the clarification here is the command running on heroku this is a discrepancy between linux (heroku) and mac: /app/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64\" -q --dpi 100    --margin-top 0 --margin-bottom 0 --margin-left 0 --margin-right 0  --page-size \"Letter\"   \"file:////tmp/wicked_pdf20140105-2-1y9dhhn.html\" \"/tmp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20140105-2-rerdwb.pdf\

Comment: @NicholasStock: try without `--page-size` argument.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, no change though! /app/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64\" -q --dpi 100    --margin-top 0 --margin-bottom 0 --margin-left 0 --margin-right 0    \"file:////tmp/wicked_pdf20140106-2-8g8gi1.html\" \"/tmp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20140106-2-19qg0oc.pdf\

Comment: @NicholasStock: grrr ;( Sorry then, this solved problem on my unix box, I don't know what else could be the problem ;(